# Error when deploying to Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I've been deploying different versions of my app to google cloud over the last few days. After successfully uploading a few large files, all of a sudden I receive this error:

ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Cannot upload file [/Users/tgb29/Desktop/shaforms2/python-docs-samples/appengine/flexible/storage/shaforms.bin], which has size [803047362] (greater than maximum allowed size of [33554432]). Please delete the file or add to the skip_files entry in your application .yaml file and try again.

I'm not sure what changed in one deployment.

Answer (score 2):

I think this problem is releted to Google App Engine Standard java 8. 
When I used java11, problem disappeared.

This app.yaml works for me:

```
runtime: java11
env: standard
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

launch by:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

App Engine has a limit regarding the number of files and the size they can have when deploying a new version, quoting the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Deployments):

> An application is limited to
>   10,000 uploaded files per version. **Each file is limited to a maximum
>   size of 32 megabytes**. Additionally, if the total size of all files for
>   all versions exceeds the initial free 1 gigabyte, then there will be a
>   $ 0.026 per GB per month charge.

Since your file `shaforms.bin` seems to be above this limit, you cannot deploy the version as long as it contains this file.

The solution would be to deploy your application without this file, for example, in the Python Standard runtime you can add the [skip_files flag](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#skip_files) to ignore certain files, in your case you could do it by adding the following lines to the `app.yaml` configuration file:

```
skip_files:
- /Users/tgb29/Desktop/shaforms2/python-docs-samples/appengine/flexible/storage/shaforms.bin
```

As well, if you need this file to be served from your application, the best would be to upload it to [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) and serve it from there, by using the [Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python).

Comment: but I need the file for the app to work, so uploading without it isn't the solution. I fixed this by switching from standard environment to flex environment and specifying cpu and memory resources in my app.yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.

Updating my Gcloud CLI version to 406.0.0 Solved the error.

I was earlier having version 155.0.0 when I had faced this issue.

Some additional notes - Using 155.0.0 with Flex App Engine did not give the error. The error had come only with standard App Engine and was fixed by updating the GCloud version to 406.0.0