# How to reduce ktor App file size for Google App Engine Deployment

Tags: google-app-engine, gradle, google-cloud-platform, ktor

I am trying to deploy app.yaml file to my Google App Engine project which I built using Ktor + gradle and I get this error,

ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Cannot upload file [the file], which has size [43355410] (greater than maximum allowed size of [33554432]). Please delete the file or add to the skip_files entry in your application .yaml file and try again.

I am not using any images or videos in my projects, its pure Kotlin code but the project is 49.2MB. It seems like all the space is being occupied by the libraries I use. All of these libraries are essential to my project, how do I reduce the file size for Google App Engine since I cannot add the app.yaml file now. Strangely the project does upload when I use 'gradle appengineDeploy' command but not when I use 'gcloud app deploy app.yaml'

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue you can set `runtime` in the `app.yml` file to `java11` (I've tested it). The quote from the [relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58923787/13963150):

> I think this problem is related to Google App Engine Standard java 8.
> When I used java11, the problem disappeared.